# Upwork add ons for chromium

Tags: plugins

I am using ubuntu 14.04 . I recently switched to ubuntu from windows. I am a freelancer. I work on upwork . In windows I used upwathcer to find the job and desktop notification . Will you please give me a solution about this . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Dear thank you very much to response me . I am using ubuntu jast two days . So will you please give me any link ? It will so beneficial for me .

Comment: What is "upwatcher"? You can install any browser add-ons in Ubuntu as well as in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

From - https://support.upwork.com/hc/en-us/articles/211064108

> Ubuntu 14.10
>
> Download the Upwork Team app installation package.
>
> In the file
>   `/etc/sysctl.conf`, set the `shmax` kernel parameter value by adding the
>   lines:
>
> ```
> kernel.shmmax=268435456  
> kernel.shmall=268435456
> ```
>
> Restart the
>   system.

Follow the download link and log in.

To edit the system file,

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo